# PHP creating dates from different string formats

Tags: php, date

I need to import data from excel, and I can not control the format of the date that the user can use (sometimes it’s a string).
When I try:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat(‘m-d-Y’, $string)
```

If the format of the string is different (e.g 2007-07-14) the PHP display an error:

> The separate symbol cannot be found.

Is there any solution to validate a date string and create a date for any possible format ???

Comment: Use strtotime first. Then attempt the conversion.

Comment: You've got tilde's in your code instead of apostrophe's, let's hope that was just a copy/paste error in StackOverflow?

Comment: @snh this is my first time I use stackover flow app to ask a question this is why.

Comment: @adam using strtotime worked well thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked well for me is using strtotime as @adam suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Carbon is quite smart in parsing dates of different formats, however this will require some testing with different formats.

Use the `parse()` function:

```
Carbon::parse('Monday next week'); 
Carbon::parse('2018-06-15 12:34:00', 'UTC');
Carbon::parse('02-31-1999');
```

Check out the documentation for all available formats and how it works:
[Carbon API docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)

Comment: the problem with Carbon::parse is that it throws an error if the format of the date string is wrong instead of returning false as strtotime do.

Comment: Well ya, if a date is wrong, the date is wrong, carbon is used to parse and mutate actual dates, not strings of incorrect dates. An **exact** match of your question is documented in the Carbon documentation. But fair enough, if strtotime worked, fantastic.